# How to survive when playing in mid (middle) lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

Normally when I play LoL PVP I usually go top or bot, and I find that it is much easier to survive. However in mid lane there are plenty of areas for me to get ambushed and get killed.

Should I be stocking up on wards, or what?

Comment: Mid lane is a lane of mindgames and manipulation. Wards help but if you have good communication skills and a team(specifically the jungler) that is willing to work with you, you can save the gold you would spend on wards and focus more on making your champion stronger as fast as you can. If you have spare gold though after going back each time, buying a ward or two is always a good idea as it gives your team better vision control over the map when placed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surviving mid lane is definitely a whole different ball game compared to top and bot.

Not only are there 2 sides to get ambushed from but you need at least 2 wards to cover both sides enough to comfortably not get ganked, and push a tower. Typically the most wards you should put down is 2, and hope your jungle is nice enough to ward for you as well. That way you can have all 4 ward spots covered.

[image]

Ignore the extra stuff this was the first google image of the map I could find that worked, the 4 spots I have circled are the 4 most important ward spots for mid.

I personally will ward the spot with the bush that is on my side, and thats it. I will then stick to that side no matter what. I might even ask the jungler to sit top or bottom depending on enemy jungle wanting to babysit my opponent or not and which side im on.

Unless I am laning with a champion with no escape I find it pointless to waste gold early game on wards. Even then I can usually comfortable sit under my tower and win CS all game.

The best way to survive mid lane is to use a champ that has some sort of cc or escape. Then not make simple mistakes like pushing to hard unless you notice the jungle is ganking top or bot and your opponent is either dead or ported back.

Comment: You should mention the importance of analyzing the enemy composition. If the enemy jungler is some movespeed monster like Rammus or Hecarim, or has a huge gap closer like Zac, or has massive CC like Fiddle or Warwick, or is a very bad ganker like Shyvana, all of that affects your ward/aggression strategy.

Comment: @Hackworth I mentioned mostly wards because that is the example he gave. Adding anything else would make the answer to broad and therefore a bad answer. If he wants details about team composition then I could go on for days. And in reality I use the same survival strategy for each Jungler. The only thing that changes is how hard I push or the risks I take.